# Searching an element in an Array using Recursive Function in C Language

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am a beginner to arrays in recursion so need some guidance.
I am trying to find whether an element is present in an array or not.

```c
// Program to find whether an element exist in an array or not.
#include <stdio.h>
int arr[5]= {1,2,3,4,5};

int fooSearch(int array1[],int N,int i, int X)
{
    if(i==N)
      return 0;
    else if (array1[i]==X)
      return 1;
    else 
      return fooSearch(array1,N,i++,X); 
}

// N denotes total size 5
// i counter that moves from 0 to 4 and eliminate recursion when it reaches 5
// X is the element to be found


int main() {
    fooSearch(arr,5,0,3);
    return 0;
}
```

The error I obtained is `Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)`.

Please guide me what wrong I am doing with this code.

Answer (score 2):

`i++` is a post-fix increment, which increments `i` *after* the expression containing it is evaluated. Thus, every call to `fooSearch` effectively becomes to `fooSearch(array1, N, 0, X)`. Recursion is endless, hence the segfault (or a stack-overflow on my compiler). (You can confirm that `i` is unchanging by placing `printf("%d\n", i)` at the top of the function.)

Fix this by using pre-fix increments, which increment the variable *before* evaluation.

```
return fooSearch(array1, N, ++i, X);
```

Or use `i+1`, since you won't be reusing the local variable anyways.

```
return fooSearch(array1, N, i+1, X);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I understood the mistake I was making.

Answer (score 1):

While calling `fooSearch()` recursively pass `i+1` instead of `i++` as post increment `i++` doesn't change `i` in the argument. For e.g

```
fooSearch(array1,N,i+1,X);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, also can you guide me to some tutorials on understanding array in recursions.

Answer (score 1):

to find whether an element is present in an array or not.

you can initialize number of array elements, Let's say 10 elements:

```
int num[10]= {2,3,5,6,1,8,4,9,0,7};
```

Then, Creating *for* loop for checking if number 9 is not in array then continue until the condition is false then print the element location.

```
  for(i=0; i<10; i++){

    if(num[i] != 9){
      continue;
    }

    printf("9 is found here\n%d",i);
    break;
  }
```

At the end, You write an if condition to check if the loop is ended and print not found.

```
  if(i==10){
    printf("Not Found");
  }
```

The full code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int num[10]={2,3,5,6,1,8,4,9,0,7};
int i;

int main(void){

  for(i=0; i<10; i++){

    if(num[i] != 9){
      continue;
    }

    printf("9 is found here\n%d",i);
    break;
  }

  if(i==10){
    printf("Not Found");
  }

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, I was confused with the use of recursion and array passing. Your answer is helpful for those who need the iterative method of the same problem. I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `++i` or `i+1` instead of `i++`.

`i++` is a post increment operator, so the value of `i` that will go to the function will not change.

Just use `++i` or `i+1` and you will get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean checkNumber(int input[], int x) {
    
    int n=input.length;
    if(n==0)
        return false;
    
    if(input[0]==x)
    {
        return true;
    }
      int small[]=new int[n-1];

    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        small[i-1]=input[i];
    }
    
    return checkNumber(small, x);
    
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```c
// Program to find whether an element exist in an array or not.
// Number of elements of array is N, the number to search is X
#include <stdio.h>
int arr[]= {1,2,3,4,5};

int fooSearch(int array1[],int N,int i, int X)
{   if(i==N)
      return 0;
    else if (array1[i]==X)
      return 1;
    else 
      i=i+1;
      return fooSearch(array1,N,i,X); 
}

int main() {
int x = fooSearch(arr,5,0,9);
printf("%d",x);
return 0;
}
```